# Can not run http page on apache2

Tags: apache2, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-14.04

i following this steps: [Ssl-apache-ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04), and i create new host in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled, content of file is :

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so 
NameVirtualHost *:443
NameVirtualHost floorwood.dev:80
<VirtualHost *:443> 
    DocumentRoot "/home/jan/PhpstormProjects/floorwood/" 
    ServerName floorwood.dev 
    SSLEngine on 
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
</VirtualHost>
```

And after restart apache i had this error:

> [so:warn] [pid 21963] AH01574: module ssl_module is already loaded, skipping

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error it's a warning.

The first line in your config snippet must be repeated elsewhere in your config so just remove it from here:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

Comment: Thanks, this help me.